# Using cat() with a call object

Tags: r

Is there any way to show a `call` object (the result of `match.call()`) using `cat()`?

For example:

```
func <- function(...) {
 return(match.call())
}
result <- func(x=3)
print(result)
# func(x = 3) - Exactly what I want.
cat(result)
# Erro em cat(list(...), file, sep, fill, labels, append) : 
#  argumento 1 (tipo 'language') não suportado por 'cat'
```

I want save the command used in a .txt file, so I can't use print (At least, I think i can't). I searched for `print.call()` function, but I didn't find it.

I tried `paste(result)`, too, but it returns only the function's name and the parameter's values (in the example, only `func` and `3`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either `format` or `deparse` to transform the `call` object `result` into a `character` string. Then, you can use `cat`:

```
cat(format(result))
# func(x = 3)

cat(deparse(result))
# func(x = 3)
```